# How should I add new migrations when the migrations are in another project using cli?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a solution with 3 projects as follows:

> -Project.Api (A .net-core project which contains startup.cs and connection string)
>
> -Project.Service (A .netstandard project which contains migrations, DbContext, etc)
>
> -Project.Domain (A .netstandard project which contains the entities)

I am getting this error when trying to add new migrations from cli by running this command:

```
cd Project.Api     
dotnet ef migrations add DoSth
```

> Your target project 'Project.Api' doesn't match your migrations
>   assembly 'Project.Service'. Either change your target project or
>   change your migrations assembly. Change your migrations assembly by
>   using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b
>   => b.MigrationsAssembly("Project.Api")). By default, the migrations assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext. Change
>   your target project to the migrations project by using the Package
>   Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing
>   "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the migrations project.

**Besides, I am not using visual studio and I have to work with cli.**

When I change the migrations assembly in the Startup.cs to 'Project.Api', the command runs with no error, but the problem is that the migrations are added under the 'Project.Api' and I don't want this because I want them under the 'Project.Service'.

I also tried to change the target assembly to 'Project.Service', but I got this error:

> Startup project 'Project.Service.csproj' targets framework
>   '.NETStandard'. There is no runtime associated with this framework,
>   and projects targeting it cannot be executed directly.To use the
>   Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools with this project, add
>   an executable project targeting .NET Core or .NET Framework that
>   references this project, and set it as the startup project using
>   --startup-project; or, update this project to cross-target .NET Core or .NET Framework. For more information on using the EF Core Tools
>   with .NET Standard projects, see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2034781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do was to change my working directory to the one that contains the migrations, then execute the command to add migrations and specify my startup project.

```
cd Project.Service

dotnet ef migrations add Add_Admin --startup-project ../Project.Api/Project.Api.csproj
```